# generate models and database using doctrine yml file in modular structure zend project

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I have been using doctrine with zend in a project without modules. It is working fine.

But now I am working on zend project with different modules in it. structure is something like that

```
application
---modules
------admin
---------models
---------controllers
---------views
```

I have a yml schema

```
options:
    type: INNODB
    collate: utf8_general_ci
    charset: utf8
User:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name: string(255)
    email: string(300)
```

and I am runing this command on shell to generate models and db.

```
shell> ./doctrine build-all-reload
```

and it is generate the models directly under APPLICATION folder. 
While I want to generate the models in APPLICATION -> MODULES -> ADMIN -> MODELS
folder

Please guide me, what configuration I need to do to achieve above results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a configuration array with 'models_path' to the Doctrine_Cli constructor.

```
$config = array(
    'models_path' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin/models'
);

$cli = new Doctrine_Cli($config);
```

See http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/utilities/en#command-line-interface for more about the cli configuration options.

Comment: Hi Jody, I am really thankful to you for this. I am using path setup in doctrine.models_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/admin/models" in application.ini. which works fine. one way of doing is that I will create module specific doctrine cli files in each module and run them using its own configuration.ini but there would be some file redundancy. second could be that I keep informatin in application.ini and some how pass the parameter(module name) to command line. I don't know how to do second solution which seems better by passing the parameter to command line. Any Idea?

Comment: I'm not sure how ZF and Doctrine work together with the configuration, but I think you can pass a command line argument to the doctrine cli script like this:  doctrine build-all-reload models_path=/path_to_models.